# EditableCellTemplate ui-grid

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I would like to have ng-input of type number in one of the columns in ui-grid. Ideally it would look like this:
[image]

I accomplished this by using regular **`cellTemplate`**, but as I understood proper way is to use **`editableCellTemplate`**.Using **`editableCellTemplate`** I get proper behaviour, but my cell look editable only on double click and result looks like this:
[image]

Clicked cells look editable, rest not, which is not really user-friendly.
How can I have all cells in columns look as defined in **`editableCellTemplate`** even if they were not been clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the `cellTemplate` (in addition to the `editableCellTemplate`) for how the value appears when not in focus. For example...

```
 { name: 'MyColumn', displayName: 'My column', width: '12%', cellTemplate: 'yourDisplayCellTemplate', editableCellTemplate: 'yourEditableCellTemplate' },
```